# Sklearn - Error While Importing using PIP

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas

```
 from sklearn import preprocessing
```

Getting the Follwing output:

> File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Users\arunr\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py", line 75, in 
>       from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
>     File "C:\Users\arunr\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_show_versions.py", line 12, in 
>       from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

[image]

Comment: Check if you running the same python environment. You have either installed sklearn for a different environment or a dependency is installed in wrong environment.

Comment: This packaging issue is being tracked at: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15899

In the mean time you can install scikt-learn from conda-forge:

`conda install conda-forge::scikit-learn`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```